# Dojo console error objects empty

Tags: dojo, firebug, error-reporting

All of a sudden the errors that Dojo (1.8.3 from Google CDN) is spitting out empty errors, which makes debugging impossibly hard.  For example, if I forget to `require` a dependent before using it, I get the usual

```
> dojo/parser::parse() error ReferenceError {}
```

... in the error console, but I remember getting more information in the `ReferenceError` (spindown arrow was present), giving me the arguments of the error as well as the message making it easy to figure out what I had done wrong.

I have `isDebug : true` in my dojoConfig, but it just doesn't want to tell me anything anymore.

What gives?

Comment: I've been having the same problem using Dojo 1.8.3 as well. When I close my developer tool's console and then re-open it the Error had the spindown and more details as expected. Seems stupid, but you can give it a try and see if that "fixes" it for you as well.

Comment: Wow. Yea, you're right. Haha. Add as an answer and I'll accept. Thank you!

Comment: Haha, no problem. I was surprised by this behavior as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having the same problem using Dojo 1.8.3 as well. When I close my developer tool's console and then re-open it the Error had the spindown and more details as expected. Seems stupid, but give it a try and see if that at "fixes" it for you. I planned on digging a little further into this later, so if I find any additional details I will make sure to update my answer with them.