# Dojo loading templated widget into data-dojo-type

Tags: dojo

I've created a very simple HTML templated widget.

```
<div class="tool">
  <a href="" id="freehand">
    <i class="flaticon-writing9"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="tool">
  <a href="" id="polygon">
    <i class="flaticon-constellation"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

My widget declaration looks like this:

```
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
  "dojo/text!./templates/DrawingToolsWidget.html",
  "dojo/parser",
  "dojo/ready"
],
  function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template, parser, ready) {

    return declare("DrawingToolsWidget",[_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
      templateString: template,

      constructor: function() {
        console.log(this);
      }

    });
    ready(function(){
      parser.parse();
    });
  }

);
```

I try to attach it to a point in my main DOM with a data-dojo-type attribute:

```
<div id="drawing-tools-container" data-dojo-type="DrawingToolsWidget"></div>
```

But I keep getting a generic dojo/parser::parse() error Error {} which is completely useless for debugging.

My directory structure is: /index.html(main DOM) /app/DrawingToolWidget/templates/DrawingToolsWidget.html(template) /app/DrawingToolWidget/DrawingToolWidget.js(declaration)

I've also tried to attach "app/DrawingToolWidget/DrawingToolWidget" just in case it wanted the path to the widget declaration. Nope.

What am I doing wrong? Why is it so hard just to attach a fragment of markup to the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is invalid because you can only have 1 root element. I'm not sure if that's the main problem, but this might solve certain things. A quote from the documentation:

> Note that when you define a template, it can only have **one** root
>   node definition ( just like with XML documents). Multiple nodes at the
>   top level is not allowed.

The article: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/templated/

A working template would be:

```html
<div>
    <div class="tool">
        <a href="" id="freehand">
            <i class="flaticon-writing9"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tool">
        <a href="" id="polygon">
            <i class="flaticon-constellation"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The working example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6L9eE/1/).

---

About your debugging problem, do you use Google Chrome? When encountering an error, you should try to close and open the developer tools/console, if you do that, there should be a small arrow next to the `Error`, for example:

[image: Error]

As you can see here, there are 2 arrows, the left one gives you the stacktrace, while the right one (almost at the end of the error line), will give you detailed information about the error (if you click/expand it).

Comment: I didn't know there was a "one node" requirement. I saw it more as an "innerHtml" type thing. And as for the debugging, is this documented somewhere? It's an interesting workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's documented. I noticed it myself by googling it (and finding it on StackOverflow), here's the post that helped me out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14957933/1915448. It seems it happens on Firefox and Chrome, on Opera (12.16) I don't have that issue. I think it has something to do with the asynchronous loading of files.

Comment: And about the template, you should rather see it as a replacement (in stead of inner HTML). Replacing one DOM node by another makes more sense (than replacing one DOM node by multiple DOM nodes).